# np.array_split() takes dramatically longer if passing indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've noticed some strangely inefficient behavior in the Numpy np.array_split function when passing the argument to provide indices to split the dataframe on.

Data is in the following format:

```
cid, rid, value
c1, r1, xxx
c1, rN, xxx
c2, r1, xxx
c2, rN, xxx
```

I'm trying to parallelize the pivoting of this DataFrame. So what I want is to split the data into close to even chunks, but I don't want any cids to be in two chunks. (each cid needs all rids).

Even code:

```
npartitions = 12
df_split = np.array_split(df,npartitions)
Split evenly: 0.5506768226623535s
```

Uneven split:

```
df_split = np.array_split(df, [r*nrow for r in range(0, len(df), ncols//npartitions)])
Split unevenly: 44.44724416732788s
```

The issue is that this takes much much longer than I had expected.

Does anyone know why this is? When this was used to apply mp.Pool to the same dataset, this difference resulted in a difference in pivot from 5.3s to 417s which is very dramatic. Any ideas what could be a better solution?

Comment: How big is your dataframe?

Comment: You have two timing measurements, but only one piece of code. Where does each measurement come from? What's the difference between an "even" and "uneven" split?

Comment: If you provide `array_split` with a number, it just constructs the required array of split indices.  Are you sure you are producing the same number of splits?  For what it's worth, in my testing, splitting a dataframe is significantly slower than splitting the equivalent 2d array.  `split` just constructs a list of slices of the rows.  There's nothing particularly magical about the function.

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code, but also posted a solution. There was an issue with how I calculated the new indices which has been fixed. Thank you all for providing your input

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my issue was actually a problem with how I created the partitions, leading to me having way more partitions than I thought, which of course had effects on the run time.

The error is in this line of code:

```
df_split = np.array_split(df, [r*nrow for r in range(0, len(df), ncols//npartitions)])
```

Where `range(0, len(df), ncols//npartitions)` should actually be `range(0, ncols, math.ceil(ncols/npartitions) + 1)` to get the desired number of partitions.

The following was my resulting code:

```
num_cores = _find_largest_divisor(ncols, num_cores)
df_split = np.array_split(df, num_cores)
evenly = time.time() - t
print("Npartitions: {}".format(num_cores))
print("Split evenly: {}s".format(evenly))

t = time.time()
num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
indices = [r*nrows for r in range(0, ncols, ceil(ncols/num_cores))]
df_split = np.array_split(df, indices)
uneven = time.time() - t

print("Npartitions: {}".format(len(indices)))
print("Split unevenly: {}s".format(uneven))
```

With output as:

```
Npartitions: 10
Split evenly: 0.5009868144989014s
Npartitions: 12
Split unevenly: 0.6288528442382812s
```

This helped me solve the problem of splitting a dataframe into partitions while making values indivisible by the values of column